# How to conditionally shade / color a table row using datatool?

Tags: tables, datatool, shading, rowcolor

I have been trying to shade an entire row in a table conditionally on the value of an specific entry in that row.

I was trying to adapt the "stripy table" example in `datatool`, but it seems that I am messing up the new conditional statement. In the example below I kept the original `stripy table` conditional but commented it out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{filecontents*}{bogus.csv}
FirstName,Surname,StudentNo,Score
John,"Smith, Jr",102689,68
Jane,Brown,102647,75
Andy,Brown,103569,42
Z\"oe,Adams,105987,52
Clare,Verdon,104356,45
John,"Smith, Jr",102683,68
Roger,Brady,106872,58
Clare,Verdon,104356,45
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{dat}{bogus.csv}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Conditionally colored rows}\label{tab:colored_row}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llc}
\bfseries First Name &
\bfseries Surname &
\bfseries Grade (\%)%
\DTLforeach{dat}
           {\firstname=FirstName, \surname=Surname,\score=Score} %
           {\\ % skip line
           %\DTLifoddrow{ \rowcolor{blue} }{ \rowcolor{green} } % stripy conditional. works fine.
           \DTLifnumlt{\score}{60}{\rowcolors{geen}}{\rowcolors{blue}} % my conditional. no go.
           \firstname & \surname & \score} % 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{filecontents*}{bogus.csv}
FirstName,Surname,StudentNo,Score
John,"Smith, Jr",102689,68
Jane,Brown,102647,75
Andy,Brown,103569,42
Z\"oe,Adams,105987,52
Clare,Verdon,104356,45
John,"Smith, Jr",102683,68
Roger,Brady,106872,58
Clare,Verdon,104356,45
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{dat}{bogus.csv}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Conditionally colored rows}\label{tab:colored_row}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llc}
\bfseries First Name &
\bfseries Surname &
\bfseries Grade (\%)\\
  \DTLforeach{dat}
  {\firstname=FirstName, \surname=Surname,\score=Score}{
  \DTLiffirstrow{}{
  \DTLifnumlt{\score}{60}{\\\rowcolor{green}}{\\\rowcolor{blue}}
  }
  \firstname & \surname & \score} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using the `\rowcolor` command instead of `\rowcolors` did the trick (or almost did it).

The code at the bottom is compiling now, but I'm still getting the following error:

```
Misplaced \noalign. 
\rowcolor ->\noalign
{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \global \let \CT@do@color \CT@@do@color...
```

**Bottomline, I'm not really happy with the solution but I got the output I need.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{filecontents*}{bogus.csv}
FirstName,Surname,StudentNo,Score
John,"Smith, Jr",102689,68
Jane,Brown,102647,75
Andy,Brown,103569,42
Z\"oe,Adams,105987,52
Clare,Verdon,104356,45
John,"Smith, Jr",102683,68
Roger,Brady,106872,58
Clare,Verdon,104356,45
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\DTLloaddb{dat}{bogus.csv}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Conditionally colored rows}\label{tab:colored_row}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llc}
\bfseries First Name &
\bfseries Surname &
\bfseries Grade (\%)%
\DTLforeach{dat}
           {\firstname=FirstName, \surname=Surname,\score=Score} %
           {\\
           \DTLifnumlt{\score}{50}{\rowcolor{red}}{}
           \firstname & \surname & \score
           }% 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```